# Trigger a function based on the value of a radio button retrieved from the database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This function is intended to an **Edit** form, so therefore the radio buttons are initialized with the value stored in the database. Upon clicking on the radio buttons, 2 different function has to be invoked. What the function basically does is, it populates a dropdown list. **E.g.:** If the first radio button is selected the dropdown list must populate only the gents items.

**HTML CODE**

```
<td>Catalogue Type</td>
<td>
   <input type="radio" name="catalogue_type" id="catalogue_type" class="catalogue_type" <?php if($val['gents_ladies']=="Gents"){echo "checked";} ?> value="Gents" onclick="getCategoriesGents()"/>GENTS
   <input type="radio" name="catalogue_type" id="catalogue_type" class="catalogue_type" <?php if($val['gents_ladies']=="Ladies"){echo "checked";} ?> value="Ladies" onclick="getCategoriesLadies()"/>LADIES
</td>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function getCategoriesGents(){
            var request = $.ajax({
                url: "../controller/sale.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {action:'get_gents_categories'},  
                dataType: "html"
            });
            request.done(function(msg){ 
                $('#category_details').html(msg);
            }); 
            request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                return false;
            });
        }
        function getCategoriesLadies(){
                var request = $.ajax({
                    url: "../controller/sale.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {action:'get_ladies_categories'},  
                    dataType: "html"
                });
                request.done(function(msg){
                    $('#category_details').html(msg);
                }); 
                request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                    return false;
                });
        }
</script>
```

If I put `$(document).ready(function() {` on the top of the script, this doesn't work. So i have taken that out.

That is perfectly working when I click/focus on the dropdown. But what I want is when the page gets loaded itself with the PHP/Database value, I need the function to get started and populate the drop down. Any suggestions would be very grateful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
function getCategoriesGents(){
...
}
function getCategoriesLadies(){
...
}

$(document).ready(function() { 
    if(databaseVal == gents){
        getCategoriesGents()
    } else {
        getCategoriesLadies()
    }
});
```

Basically trigger a function onload depending on what the db value is.

Comment: You should pass the database value of the active radio button on the page. Once the page has loaded, you run an if else to check which function/ajax request to send depending on the value of the radio button. check this http://jsfiddle.net/0ns44mwz/ You must pass the value of the active radio button and perform a check on it.

Comment: update: instead of getting the database val, just check whichever button is or is not active then set from there http://jsfiddle.net/0ns44mwz/1/ much better solution I think haha